# Intrinsic value vs Time value of an option: what's the purpose/motivation for their definitions?

Tags: options, option-pricing

I am an actuarial student and our text has the following definitions:

> Intrinsic value: This is the payoff assuming the expiry of the
>   contract immediately rather than at some future time.
>
> Time value: Option's current price - Intrinsic Value.

I can understand what these definitions are saying, and I probably even understand the motivation for the first one: intrinsic value gives us an idea about the current position of the contract. But I am lost when it comes to motivating the definition for the time value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time value of an option, in a sense, captures all the stochastic influence on your option. Think about a call option with payoff $\max\{S_T-K,0\}$. The intrinsic value, which is just the payoff if you exercised the option immediately, depends on $S_0$ and $K$. In the Black Scholes model there are further variables such as the interest rate, dividend yield, volatility and the time to maturity which also ``somehow'' influence the option price. Their effect is then combined into the time value. By the way, if you have a European call option on an underlying which pays dividends, you may have a negative time value and the option actually costs less than its intrinsic value. For American options, the intrinsic value (= immediate payoff) is always a lower bound due to no arbitrage arguments.

Note that the decomposition in intrinsic value and time value is somehow arbitrary or not that helpful when pricing options. You rarely find a formula for the time value of an option. The time value can, as you mentioned in your question, only be calculated as a residual once you know the entire option price. Furthermore, there are economically more helpful decompositions such as the decomposition of call option prices into digital options or equivalently into exercise probabilities (and Delta).